# In Azure Workbooks Bar chart legends are getting hidden

Tags: excel, azure

We are working on creating a custom connector to ingest the data in Azure Sentinel. We are now working on workbooks. But in workbooks, in the graphs, we are facing problem, that few legends are getting hidden.

[image]

As you can see in the above image, out of 10, only 9 are displayed, and that also not complete, even though the graph panel width is set to 100%.

And if we decrease the tab size, or zoom in, then more no. of legends are getting hidden. same applies to zoom out, if we zoom out to 80% approx, then all the 10 legends will be displayed.

Can someone help me to solve the this problem, and make all the legends visible irrespective of screen size?